# emacs fullscreen interaction with gnus

Tags: emacs, fullscreen, gnus

I have just configured gnus to work inside emacs 24.3. When I run emacs, I like to have four windows open like so:

[image: desired emacs setting]

The bottom left window is gnus, when I open my inbox (or any other option) it will cover the entire terminal screen like so:

[image: undesired emacs setting]
Having the entire screen devoted to one task is not desirable and inefficient for me. I would prefer to keep all gnus related events inside that bottom left window. How can I achieve this?

1. How can I confine the operations of gnus to the bottom left window?

Let me know if you have any additional questions about my problem. All suggestions are welcome! I do not know many details about emacs configuration, other than I like it, and that it makes me more efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the variable `gnus-use-full-window` to `nil`.  That should give you the desired behaviour at least most of the time.